# Twitter OAuth returning blank array if there is no tweet

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter, twitter-oauth

I spent my last 5 hours in this issue and finally I came here for the solution.

I am doing log-in using twitter functionality in my site (Zend Framework + PHP) and everything is working fine. But I am facing the following issue in it:

If the user has no tweets (0 tweets) in his account then the

```
$tweets = json_decode($response->getBody());
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tweets);
exit;
```

Its showing me blank array. i.e. : `Array();` :-(

And if I am adding some tweets there in twitter account then its showing me the complete array along with user information like display name, image, etc...like this:

```
Array
(
    //other data
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user] => stdClass Object
            ....
            ....
            so on..
        )
)
```

Following is my code :

```
public function twitterregisterAction() {
        $path = realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/');
        set_include_path($path);
        session_start();
        require $path . "/Zend/Oauth/Consumer.php";

        $config = array(
            "callbackUrl" => "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/register/twittercallback",
            "siteUrl" => "http://twitter.com/oauth",
            "consumerKey" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "consumerSecret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        );
        $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);
// fetch a request token
        $token = $consumer->getRequestToken();

// persist the token to storage
        $_SESSION["TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN"] = serialize($token);
// redirect the user
        $consumer->redirect();
    }

    /*
     * Ticket id #16
     * twittercallbackAction method
     */

    public function twittercallbackAction() {
        $config = array(
            "callbackUrl" => "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/register/twittercallback",
            "siteUrl" => "http://twitter.com/oauth",
            "consumerKey" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "consumerSecret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        );
        $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);

        if (!$this->_getParam("denied")) {

            if (!empty($_GET) && isset($_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN'])) {
                $token = $consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, unserialize($_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN']));
            } else {
// Mistaken request? Some malfeasant trying something?
                exit('Invalid callback request. Oops. Sorry.');
            }
// save token to file
// file_put_contents('token.txt', serialize($token));
            $client = $token->getHttpClient($config);
            $client->setUri('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?');
            $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
            $client->setParameterGet('name');
            $client->setParameterGet('profile_image_url');
            $response = $client->request();
            $tweets = json_decode($response->getBody());

            $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace("userIdentity");
            Zend_Session::rememberMe(63072000); //2years
            $session->tw_id = $tweets[0]->user->id;
            $session->tw_name = $tweets[0]->user->name;
            $session->tw_image = $tweets[0]->user->profile_image_url;

            if ($session->tw_id != "") {
                $tw_id = $session->tw_id;
//Calling the function twitterAuthAction for email authentication
                $twAuthArr = $this->twitterAuthAction($tw_id);
                if ($twAuthArr['socialId'] == $tw_id) {
                    $session->userId = $twAuthArr['id'];
                    $session->email = $twAuthArr['emailId'];
                    $this->_redirect('/profile/showprofile');
                } else {
                    $user = new UserRegistration();
                    $firstname = "";
                    $lastname = "";
                    $password = "";
                    $socialtype = "twitter";
                    $email = "";
                    $socialid = $session->tw_id;
                    $result = $user->registerUser($firstname, $lastname, $socialid, $socialtype, $email, $password);
                    $session->userId = $result;
                    $this->_redirect('/register');
                }
            }
            $this->_redirect("/register");
        } else {
            $this->_redirect("/register");
        }
    }
```

My Questions are :

1) **Why its not providing user array if there is no any tweet in my twitter account (or newly created twitter account)**

2) **I want user profile details from twitter account. How can I get it?**

Need Help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as per david's answer you need to use `users/show url` there instead of using `statuses/user_timeline`. You can use curl for requesting url so you'll get the response which contains the users information.

Try with following code:

```
    $user_id = $client->getToken()->getParam('user_id');
    $trends_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=".$user_id;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $trends_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $curlout = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    
    $response = json_decode($curlout, true);

    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace("userIdentity");
    Zend_Session::rememberMe(63072000); //2years
    $session->tw_id = $response['id'];
    $session->tw_name = $response['name'];
    $session->tw_image = $response['profile_image_url'];
```

Try this. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misreading the Twitter API docs for the [statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) endpoint.

The field `user` that you identify is one of the fields *within a returned tweet*. If the user id to which you point has no tweets, then there will be no entries in the returned array, hence no user field.

If you need the user information even in the absence of any tweets, then you probably need to hit the [users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show) endpoint.